# Responsive Sidebar/sidenav displays over content (mobile only)

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

New to responsive design, this is flying over my head. My site works perfectly on desktop, and it works fine when it is resized. The upper right menu is supposed to be hidden, but on mobile devices ONLY, is displayed when landing on the homepage.

Screenshot: http://fireflyaz.com/assets/templates/posterservice-html5/images/example.jpg

Live example (problem only on mobile device): http://www.fireflyaz.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the default_modified.css, CSS for #showSlideMenu is set a width of 50%, so this shows up even when the sidebar is not open. Change the class name to #showSlideMenu.cbp-spmenu-open so the css would apply only when the sidebar is open. Your style would be as follows:

```
#showSlideMenu.cbp-spmenu-open {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: please mark our answer if it worked for you,in future it would be helpful for someone else